# Static string недоступен из-за его уровня защиты

Tags: unity3d, строки, static

Функция которая создаёт путь для сохранения файлов я поместил в отдельный скрипт. Вот она -

```
    public static string GetDataFilePath()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
            try
            {
                System.IntPtr contextWrapper = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android/content/ContextWrapper");
                System.IntPtr contextWrapperGetFilesDir = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(contextWrapper, "getFilesDir", "()Ljava/io/File;");

                using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
                {
                    using (AndroidJavaObject unityPlayerCurrentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                    {
                        System.IntPtr unityPlayerCurrentActivityRawObject = unityPlayerCurrentActivity.GetRawObject();
                        System.IntPtr filesDir = AndroidJNI.CallObjectMethod(unityPlayerCurrentActivityRawObject, contextWrapperGetFilesDir, new jvalue[0]);

                        System.IntPtr file = AndroidJNI.FindClass("java/io/File");
                        System.IntPtr fileGetAbsolutePath = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(file, "getAbsolutePath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
                        string absolutePath = AndroidJNI.CallStringMethod(filesDir, fileGetAbsolutePath, new jvalue[0]);

                        return absolutePath;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log(e.ToString());
                return Application.persistentDataPath;
            }
#else
        return Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif
    }
```

Потом через другой скрипт я пытаюсь использовать его -

```
public GetPath GetPathScript;
string Path = $"{GetPathScript.GetDataFilePath()}/{fileName}";
```

И получаю ошибку -

> Доступ к члену "GetPath.GetDataFilePath()" через ссылку на экземпляр невозможен; вместо этого уточните его, указав имя типа.

А если убрать public то получаю ошибку -

> 'GetPath.GetDataFilePath()" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты.

**Как это исправить?**

П.Н.
[image]

Comment: `static string GetDataFilePath()` использует модификатор "по умолчанию" `private`. В Вашем же случае нужен `public`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Я же сказал что когда пишу public тоже получаю ошибку. Вы прочитали вопрос не до конца

Comment: И когда при инициализации статического поля вы пытаетесь использовать нестатические поля, то нет ничего удивительного, что он ругается на отсутствие экземпляра, потому что его нет в статическом контексте

Comment: метод должен быть public. А вы его вызываете неправильно. Не `GetPathScript.GetDataFilePath()`, а `GetPath.GetDataFilePath()`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский метод публичный и я его вызываю правильно.Обратите внимание на имени переменной. Имя GetPathScript а не GetPath.

Comment: `GetPathScript` имя переменной, а вызывать нужно именно через класс `GetPath`, но, я надеюсь, это и так стало понятно.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Хорошо спасибо. Но я решил проблему немного по другому. Я создал публичную переменную и присваивал его значение функции. И теперь переменную использую))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сослаться на `pubilc static` член класса через ссылку на экземпляр, о чем вам и говорит компилятор:

> Доступ к члену "GetPath.GetDataFilePath()" через ссылку на экземпляр
>   невозможен; вместо этого уточните его, указав имя типа.

Вместо этого напишите

`ИмяКласса.ИмяСтатическойПеременной`

или

`ИмяКласса.ИмяСтатическогоМетода()`

то есть в Вашем случае

`GetPath.GetDataFilePath()`

---

Для того, чтобы работал Ваш вариант(обратиться через ссылку на экземпляр), необходимо чтобы метод был не статический

Comment: Имя класса GetPath

Comment: значит `GetPath.GetDataFilePath()`, это уже образовалось в комментариях =)

Comment: Я скриншот оставил если надо